# Firebase cloud notification localization

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

Trying to get localization keys to work with firebase and nodes firebase.admin utility but cannot get it to work. 
I receive a messageId when sending and no errors at all so a little stuck.

I use a Firebase Function to send notifications so everything is running within firebase.

```
admin.messaging().sendToTopic("my_topic", {
    "notification": {
      "titleLocKey" : "FRXT",
      "bodyLocKey" : "FRXB",
      "bodyLocArgs" : "['test']"
    }
  }).then(function(resp){
    res.send(200, resp)
  })
```

I guess i'm doing something wrong here that i just cannot see so if there are any smart people out there please give a shout. The keys used are in the iOS localization string file. If i just use title and body the push work fine also.

Comment: Sry i couldn't understand the problem ur facing... can u be more specific on what ur trying to achieve? r u trying to fetch the "bodyLocKey" value on client side?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @José: No sorry I did not. Asked support as-well, but with no solution to my problem. Sent the payload directly to APNS and it worked perfectly, so continued to use APNS directly since we do not have androids yet.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, the payload should be:

```
{
    "android": {
        "notification": {
          "title_loc_key" : "notification_title",
          "body_loc_key" : "notification_message"
        }
    }
}
```

The localization strings should be declared in the strings.xml file.